# Using input statements as parameters in functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, user-input

I'm trying to use the results of some input statements as parameters in a function. I've tried putting the input statements before the function and then calling the function up afterwards, like this:

```
s=input("Enter the message:")
raw_key=input("Enter the raw key for columnar transposition:")
method=input("Enter the key generation method:")

def encryptColumnar(s,raw_key,method):
    if method==1:
       numkey=key1(raw_key)
    if method==2:
        numkey=key2(raw_key)
    return(columnar(s,numkey))

encryptColumnar(s,raw_key,method)
```

but it just gives me the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'numkey' referenced before assignment`. If I just put the input statements before the function, they'll prompt me for input, but they won't recognize that the input is supposed to be used as the function's parameters.

Thanks very much for the help!

EDIT: NEW CODE:

This is currently the code I'm working with:

```
s=input("Enter the message:")
raw_key=input("Enter the raw key for columnar transposition:")
method=input("Enter the key generation method:")

def encryptColumnar(s,raw_key,method):
    if method=='1':
       numkey=key1(raw_key)
    if method=='2':
        numkey=key2(raw_key)
    return(columnar(s,numkey))

encryptColumnar(s,raw_key,method)
```

It doesn't give me the UnboundLocalError anymore, but it also doesn't print anything after I give the parameters to the input statement prompts.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback of the error?

Comment: If you're running this on Python 3.x, `input` will not `eval()` the user's response like the Python 2 version does - it will return it as a string. Therefore your conditions `method == 1` etc. will never be satisfied, leading to `numkey` being undefined.

Comment: try `int(input("Enter the message:"))` etc..

Comment: @LukasGraf I've modified the function like this: method='1' and method='2' but now it's giving me an "invalid syntax" error. Advise?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I modified the method input statement like this: method=int(input('Enter the key generation method:")) but it's still giving me the same UnboundLocalError as I posted above.

Comment: @hooliaquoolia you mistakenly used the assignment operator `=` instead of the equals operator `==` - once you fix that it should do the trick.

Comment: @LukasGraf sorry about that! I replaced it with the equals operator but it's still giving me the same UnboundLocalError as I posted above.

Comment: @hooliaquoolia try printing your values after you read them from the user for debugging: `print(repr(method))`

Comment: @hooliaquoolia, also, please state which Python version you're using (in the question) and edit your question to contain the exact, up-to-date code you're currently trying.

Comment: @LukasGraf It's giving me '1'. It's not giving me the UnboundLocalError anymore, I took the int() out of method input statement, but even though I called up the encryptColumnar function below, it's still not printing anythign after I give my parameters to the input statements.

Comment: Does your `encryptColumnar()` function print anything? If not, you need to print its result, like `print(encryptColumnar(s,raw_key,method))`

Comment: @LukasGraf fantastic! I'm sorry it turned out to be such a basic oversight, but thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running this on Python 3.x, [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#input) will not `eval()` the user's response like the Python 2 version does - it will return it as a string (it basically behaves like Python 2's `raw_input`). Therefore your conditions `method == 1` etc. will never be satisfied, leading to `numkey` being undefined.

So you have to options:

- Either convert the user's response to an `int` and test against integers:

```
import sys

method = input("Enter the key generation method:")

try:
    method = int(method)
except ValueError:
    print("You need to enter an integer!")
    sys.exit(1)

# ...

if method == 1:
    # ...
```

- or you accept the user's input as is, and test against string values:

```
import sys

method = input("Enter the key generation method:")

if method == '1':
    # ...
elif method == '2':
    # ...
else:
    print("Unknown method!")
    sys.exit(1)
```

See the documentation on [exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) for the details of the `except` statement, and the docs on the [`if` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) for details on the `elif` clause. They're not strictly relevant to your problem here, but as @TheSoundDefense pointed out, the error handling of your code could be improved a bit, so there you go ;-)

Comment: You're welcome. The fact that you edited your question multiple times and responded (quickly!) to the follow-up questions that people asked helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `numkey` is not guaranteed to be set by the end of `encryptColumnar`. If `method` is 3, or anything besides 1 or 2, then there is no `numkey=` statement that gets executed, so it's never assigned. Then when you get to `return`, you get an error because you're trying to return a variable that was never assigned. At the very least, you should put an `else` statement in to make sure `numkey` is covered.

Comment: The function is such that the user would know to only enter 1 or 2 as the method parameter (there are only 2 ways of generating the raw_key). I'm getting the error even when I enter 1 or 2 (I don't have a reason to put anything other than 1 or 2). Should I still put an else statement like this?: else: numkey=numkey or some such?

Comment: @hooliaquoolia first try taking Lukas Graf's suggestion, if you are using Python 3.x.